# Change background color based on value and row count

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm using VBA and I would like to ask for help with regards to the Excel I have created. I want to change the background color if a cell has value and if row count is even. 
Here's my code:

```
Sub ChangeColor()
Dim rw as Variant
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("B10:H10000")

For each rw In rng.Rows
  If rw.Row Mod 2 = 0 And (I dont know what to put here) Then
     rw.Interior.Color = RGB (183,222,232)
  End If
Next rw
End Sub
```

And if I may ask how do I make the process of my application faster than normal since it will slow down because of the data that has been inputted (more or less 1000 + or almost 10k).

I already solved the row count is even, kindly help me for the value.

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting? Use a formula like `=AND(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,NOT(ISBLANK(A1)))`.

Comment: Conditional formatting on cell or should I place it inside a macro? I was thinking of placing an if statement like the code I created so that It will be done programatically. Anyways thanks for the idea and the help but I still choose to do it inside macro

Comment: "Conditional formatting" is a control found in the Styles section on the home tab of the toolbar.  You will need to select the range then click new rule and use a formula.  This will update much more dynamically than running the code above, so it is probably the best solution.  If you search on Google I'm sure you can find a step by step tutorial for creating a conditional format if you need more assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I'll give it a try. Thanks for the help rdh and Davis

Comment: Is my formula correct guys `=AND(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,NOT(ISBLANK(B10:H10000))`

Comment: So this CF is for 1 cell only. I tried it and it only formats a single cell. Thanks for the quick response by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CF should be a lot quicker than VBA for this:

[image: SO23637299 example]

The formula I chose is:

```
=AND(ISEVEN(ROW()),B10<>"")
```